# Hole in floor using the building editor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the easiest way to define a hole in a floor using the building editor?

Background is: I want to model a building with an elevator, using the elevator plugin.
What I've done is loading the example elevator world and adding a building model I've created before. Doing this I now have an elevator and a building, but if the elevator is inside of it it can't change floors because the collision is still there.

How could I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13985/hole-in-floor-using-the-building-editor/) by [AL](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2727/al/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's no easy way to open a hole in the building editor. One way would be to create a building which has stairs in the bottom floor where the elevator would go, and after the SDF file is saved, then go into the file and delete the `Stairs_*` link.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1